# Using python to dump hexadecimals into YAML

Tags: python, hex, yaml, dump

Now I'm dumping into a YAML document. It's working as it should for the most part. When I try to dump a hexadecimal such as "0x2A" it converts to 42. Isn't there any way to maintain it's hexadecimal format? A string won't work sadly. And int( 0x2A, 16) also just gives me a 42.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for `hex(0x2a) == hex(42) == '0x2a'`.

Unless you're looking for a way to convince your existing dumping function to use hexadecimal instead of decimal notation...

---

Answering to your comment below, if the problem is that you want upper case letters for the hexadecimal digits (but lower case for the `0x`) then you have to use string formatting.  You can choose one of the following:

```
"0x%02X" % 42                     # the old way
"0x{:02X}".format(42) == "0x2A"   # the new way
```

In both cases, you'll have to print the `0x` explicitly, followed by a hexadecimal number of at least two digits in upper case, left-padded with a zero if your number has only one digit.  This is denoted by the format `02X`, same as in C's `printf`.

Comment: Sadly that won't work :(. I need in integer format not str. But when I convert to integer it becomes a decimal >:C. 
(ex: int(0x0) -> 0)

Comment: Integers are integers.  They are not decimal or hexadecimal; they are sequences of bits.  It's how you print them that makes the difference.

Comment: No I need the 0x2A Notation. How do I get that?

Answer (score 11):

This should do it:

```
>>> import yaml
>>> class HexInt(int): pass
... 
>>> def representer(dumper, data):
...     return yaml.ScalarNode('tag:yaml.org,2002:int', hex(data))
... 
>>> yaml.add_representer(HexInt, representer)
>>> yaml.dump({"n": HexInt(42)})
'{n: 0x2a}\n'
```

Answer (score 3):

Representing all `int` in hex format, without a `HexInt` class, can be done using:

```
def hexint_presenter(dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_int(hex(data))
yaml.add_representer(int, hexint_presenter)
```

With reference to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9101562/3989931).

Comment: this solution doesn't work if `safe_dump` is used instead of `dump`