# yaml dump hex numbers or avoid autoquoting of hex string in yaml output

Tags: python, yaml

I'm trying to generate yaml output from a Python program where I want certain numbers to appear in hex form:

```
{ mask: 0xff, value: 27 }
```

No problem, I thought, I'll just replace that number with it's hex string before dumping:

```
data["mask"] = hex(data["mask"])
```

but now when I dump the data structure, the number appears in quotes (`'`):

```
{ mask: '0xff', value: 27 }
```

How can I avoid having yaml.dump insert those quotes around the hex value?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18700642/489590

Comment: You should thinj about why you want this.  Both hexadecimal and decimal represent integers.  When you read the integer from the YAML file, it will be read as the same integer no matter what format it was in.  If the format matters, you need to make it a string to ensure you'll be able to recover the format latter; if only the value matters, then the format doesn't matter.