# Handling hex values and keeping comments in YAML files

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I am not able to load a hex value from a YAML file while keeping comments. I need to dump it as a hex number and not a hex string. The structure of the output file must be the same as the structure of the input file as it is read by another program.

This is the general structure of my YAML file:

```
myvalue: 0x12 # This is my value
othervalue: "foo"
bar:
  value1: true # This value is true
  value2: 4627
```

Following a [similar question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666816/using-python-to-dump-hexadecimals-into-yaml) answer I have tried to add a representer to handle hex data:

```
class HexInt(int): pass
 
def representer(dumper, data):
    return ruamel.yaml.ScalarNode('tag:yaml.org,2002:int', hex(data))

ruamel.yaml.add_representer(HexInt, representer)
```

But to load the hex data as a string, I had to set the typ parameter on my YAML object to "base", thus getting rid of comments.

Is there a way to both load and dump hex values, while keeping comments intact ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "similar question" you refer to is based on PyYAML, and although `ruamel.yaml` has been dirived
from that, there are now fairly large differences in capapbilities, although some mechanisms (like
adding representers) are still using the same methods.

Although `ruamel.yaml` initially was developed to support preserving comments. It also combined the mostly
equal, duplicated, source trees for Python 2 and 3 existing in PyYAML (to allow for implementing missing
YAML 1.1 features as well as upgrading to YAML 1.2)

Since then other "preservations" have been implemented as well including (optional) scalar quoting,
anchor/alias names, and **number formatting**.

Although it is possible to write your own representer that can handle comments, that is non-trivial.
If you want to load (and dump) a hex value just use `ruamel.yaml` as is, and manipulate
the value (without knowing what type it is), or use the built-in type for hexadecimal integers explicitly:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
myvalue: 0x12 # This is my value
othervalue: "foo"
bar:
  value1: true # This value is true
  value2: 4627
"""
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
org = int(data['myvalue'])
print(f'{data["myvalue"]=}')
data['myvalue'] //= org  # set to 0x01
data['myvalue'] *= 42    # and multiply
data['bar']['value1'] = ruamel.yaml.scalarint.HexInt(42)
comment = data['bar'].ca.items['value1'][2]
comment.value = comment.value.replace(' is ', ' used to be ')
print()
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
data["myvalue"]=18

myvalue: 0x2a # This is my value
othervalue: "foo"
bar:
  value1: 0x2a # This value used to be true
  value2: 4627
```