# Converting json file to custom json

Tags: json, python-3.x

I needs to convert json files to custom json.

I know basics of python, but I don't know as much to make it possible so I'm asking for a little help.

I have this json:

```
{"__class":"Tape","Clips":[{"__class":"MotionClip","Id":4280596098,"TrackId":4094799440,"IsActive":1,"StartTime":180,"Duration":48,"ClassifierPath":"world/maps/error/timeline/moves/error_intro_walk.msm","GoldMove":0,"CoachId":0,"MoveType":0,"Color":[1,0.929412,0.443137,0.368627],"MotionPlatformSpecifics":{"X360":{"__class":"MotionPlatformSpecific","ScoreScale":1,"ScoreSmoothing":0,"LowThreshold":0,"HighThreshold":1},"ORBIS":{"__class":"MotionPlatformSpecific","ScoreScale":1,"ScoreSmoothing":0,"LowThreshold":0,"HighThreshold":1},"DURANGO":{"__class":"MotionPlatformSpecific","ScoreScale":1,"ScoreSmoothing":0,"LowThreshold":0,"HighThreshold":1}}},{"__class":"MotionClip","Id":2393481294,"TrackId":4094799440,"IsActive":1,"StartTime":372,"Duration":48,"ClassifierPath":"world/maps/error/timeline/moves/error_ve_opening.msm","GoldMove":0,"CoachId":0,"MoveType":0,"Color":[1,0.533333,0.776471,0.466667],"MotionPlatformSpecifics":{"X360":{"__class":"MotionPlatformSpecific","ScoreScale":1,"ScoreSmoothing":0,"LowThreshold":0,"HighThreshold":1},"ORBIS":{"__class":"MotionPlatformSpecific","ScoreScale":1,"ScoreSmoothing":0,"LowThreshold":0,"HighThreshold":1},"DURANGO":{"__class":"MotionPlatformSpecific","ScoreScale":1,"ScoreSmoothing":0,"LowThreshold":0,"HighThreshold":1}}}

...
{"__class":"PictogramClip","Id":1172003179,"TrackId":575629419,"IsActive":1,"StartTime":6408,"Duration":30,"PictoPath":"world/maps/error/timeline/pictos/pr_mooncatch_pu.png","CoachCount":4294967295},{"__class":"PictogramClip","Id":1048016701,"TrackId":575629419,"IsActive":1,"StartTime":6360,"Duration":30,"PictoPath":"world/maps/error/timeline/pictos/pr_mooncatch_pu.png","CoachCount":4294967295}],"TapeClock":0,"TapeBarCount":1,"FreeResourcesAfterPlay":0,"MapName":"Error","SoundwichEvent":""}.
```

Full file is here (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_QxxJQfeeeWyQUChTOpD04eGZ-7y45CS/view?usp=sharing). It has 2 types of classes in 2 parts. It comes from a game server. 
I want to convert all numbers, they're all decimal, to hex in this format 00 00 00 00. (example: 150 is 00 00 00 96)
I don't need anything listed under MotionPlatformSpecifics and Color so that can be deleted.
And at the end saved as new json file.
Output for this snippet of input should be:

```
{"__class":"Tape","Clips":[{"__class":"MotionClip","Id":FF24B682,"TrackId":F411AE50,"IsActive":00000001,"StartTime":000000B4,"Duration":00000030,"ClassifierPath":"world/maps/error/timeline/moves/error_intro_walk.msm","GoldMove":00000000,"CoachId":00000000,"MoveType":00000000,

...
{"__class":"PictogramClip","Id":3E77773D,"TrackId":224F686B,"IsActive":000001,"StartTime":000018D8,"Duration":0000001E,"PictoPath":"world/maps/error/timeline/pictos/pr_mooncatch_pu.png","CoachCount":FFFFFFFF}],"TapeClock":00000000,"TapeBarCount":00000001,"FreeResourcesAfterPlay":00000000,"MapName":"Error","SoundwichEvent":""}.
```

Edit: I've figured out how to load json file in python.

```
import json


f = open(r"C:\Users\Username\Desktop\data.json", "r")
data = json.load(f)
```

Comment: You're asking a bunch of different questions at once. I recommend narrowing this question down to the first thing you're stuck on and describing what you've tried and where exactly you're stuck. Also, please provide everything necessary to answer the question in the question itself, without requiring the answerer to go to external links.

Comment: I've narrowed it down as much as I could. Json file is quite long so I included link to full file as well as part of file.

Comment: Can you show exactly what you want your output to look like for that snippet of input?

Comment: Post is updated with example of the output.

Comment: What you're looking for isn't valid JSON, so you're basically going to have to write a whole JSON-like formatting engine, which is well out of scope for a single Q&A. There is a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100662/how-to-print-integers-as-hex-strings-using-json-dumps-in-python) that discusses some potential alternatives/workarounds that may be useful to you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9101141/12219490 This works for me somewhat. Could it be printed in hex format I want. And without 0x at the start for easier copying and pasting.

Comment: `{..    "__class": "Tape",..    "Clips": [..        {..            "__class": "MotionClip",..            "Id": 0xff24b682,..            "TrackId": 0xf411ae50,..            "IsActive": 0x1,..            "StartTime": 0xb4,..            "Duration": 0x30,..            "ClassifierPath": "world/maps/error/timeline/moves/error_intro_walk.msm",..            "GoldMove": 0x0,..            "CoachId": 0x0,..            "MoveType": 0x0..        },..        {..            ` This is ouput with code copied from comment linked in previous post.